# FirstName is not a valid value for TabTypeCode

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to pull down some envelope information using RequestStatuses.  However I get an error whenever it tries to pull in an envelope that has the pre-defined "First Name" or "Last Name" fields.  The "Full Name" field seems to work ok.  I know it says "Note that FirstName, LastName and EmailAdress tab types are not returned in this SOAP version." but is there any way to pull in envelopes with those tab types and just not get those fields?  Or is the solution to go in and replace any instances of "FirstName/LastName" with "FullName"?

**Edited 12/17:**

The error message is:  CommunicationException was unhandled by user code.  Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'RequestStatus'.  I get this when doing both RequestStatuses and RequestStatus using just the envelope ID.  The inner exception says "There is an error in XML document (1,3068)".  Expanding that gives the message "Instance validation error: 'FirstName' is not a valid value for TabTypeCode.".

Here's part of what shows up in the trace viewer:

```
<TabStatus>
<TabType>FirstName</TabType>
<Status>Signed</Status>
<XPosition>610</XPosition>
<YPosition>204</YPosition>
<TabLabel>First Name</TabLabel>
<TabName>First Name</TabName>
<TabValue>JOHN</TabValue>
</TabStatus>
<TabStatus>
<TabType>LastName</TabType>
<Status>Signed</Status>
<XPosition>229</XPosition>
<YPosition>210</YPosition>
<TabLabel>Last Name</TabLabel>
<TabName>Last Name</TabName>
<TabValue>SMITH</TabValue>
</TabStatus>
```

Comment: Where are you reading the "... these are not returned in this SOAP version" text, and what version of the SOAP api are you using?

Comment: That line came from the online API documentation located at:http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Status%20and%20Managing%20Group/TabStatus.htm

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening at this point.  Sometimes when I do "RequestStatus" an envelope will work but then if I try it again later I get the error message.  Same envelope, no changes but it randomly works sometimes and not others.

Comment: These might just be environment hiccups related to service packs and hot patches in the demo environment, what happens if you make the equivalent get status call using REST?  Are you able to reproduce?

Comment: [THIS](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeInformation) would be the equivalent call in REST

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to succesfully execute the **RequestStatuses** operation for an Envelope that contains a **FirstName** tag and a **LastName** tag (and other tag types as well), using the following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:RequestStatuses>
         <ns:EnvelopeStatusFilter>
            <ns:AccountId>a763cd1a-03ee-25y7-9b6a-6f4bf80e55lk</ns:AccountId>
            <ns:Statuses>
               <ns:Status>Any</ns:Status>
            </ns:Statuses>
            <ns:EnvelopeIds>
               <ns:EnvelopeId>D7487692-1357-4B05-8BF1-B33294185D6D</ns:EnvelopeId>
            </ns:EnvelopeIds>
         </ns:EnvelopeStatusFilter>
      </ns:RequestStatuses>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As the API documentation indicates the **FirstName** and **LastName** tags aren't included in the response, but I nonetheless receive a successful response.

Precisely what error are you receiving, and what does your (full) XML Request look like?  If you can update your question with this info, then I can try to assist with troubleshooting.  Also, I'd suggest that you try a simple **RequestStatus** operation (i.e., singular) to request explicitly the EnvelopeID that you believe to be problematic (i.e., the one with a FirstName and/or LastName tag). If that's successful, then that might indicate that the issue you're having isn't necessarily caused by the FirstName/LastName tags.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out.  It looks like the problem was being caused by templates that had the First/Last Name tags with names other than "First Name" and "Last Name".  One template they were "FirstName" and "LastName" and another one they had number appended after them (probably because they were copied/pasted at some point).  Originally when I did the "RequestStatus" on individual envelopes of these types I got the same error.  After changing the fields and testing again they worked. I'll have to wait for some envelopes of these specific types to complete before I will know for sure.

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it. It worked for the test envelopes I tried yesterday but a live one this morning had the same error. I've updated the first post with the error details.